# Google Places API (get all postal code around me)

Tags: api

I am using the blowing script to get all store around position wit 20 mile and working well but when try to using it to get postal_code do not working 
how i get all postal code around center with specific distance
code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var lat = "";
    var lng = "";
    function latClick(glocation) {
        var a = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        a.geocode({ 'address': glocation }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                var c = results;
            else
                c = "We couldn't find that location. Please try again."

            lat = c[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = c[0].geometry.location.lng();

            var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

            //sll=30.04443,31.234217&sspn=0.036703,0.084543&geocode=FU1wygEdO5jcAQ%3BFQRxygEdgJ7cASnrviELpj9YFDG6O0LolrLfeQ&mra=mift&

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: pyrmont,
                zoom: 15
            });

            var request = {
                location: pyrmont,
                radius: 200,
                types: ['store']
            };
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
        });
    }
  var map;
  var infowindow;

  function initialize() {
      latClick("Jersey City, NJ 07306, United States");
  }

  function callback(results, status) {          
      var x = "";
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          createMarker(results[i]);
          x = x + results[i].name + ", ";
      }
      alert(x);
    }
  }

  function createMarker(place) {
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(place.name);
      infowindow.open(map, this);
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Use google places api, after getting results, get the detail against its reference which would give you POSTAL CODES in address components  https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details